# Win32 Kernel32.CreateThread from assembler

Tags: multithreading, x86, assembly, disassembly, kernel32

```
Hi to all....

////////////////////////////////////////////

PUSH 214D84DD // thread id address out
PUSH 0  
PUSH 0
PUSH 214D84CD // my function address to run in the thread
PUSH 0
PUSH 0
CALL DWORD PTR DS:[4EBD1204]  // KERNEL32.CreateThread


waiting_label:
NOP
JMP waiting_label

////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I have put a breakpoint on my function (214D84CD), but after the CreateThread, in the "waiting loop" my function is not invoked.
Otherwise, if I call after CreateThread my application (and not the waiting loop) with many others threads, my function is invoked.

Why? There is some "DoEvents" api to force in my loop to call my thread function?

The thread id (214D84DD) and the return value EAX are not null.
I'm run my application in a debugger (OllyDbg). And I'm not using any compiler.

Many thanks,
Riccardo

Comment: You are pusing the arguments in the wrong order.  Use a compiler.

Comment: i think that the order is correct because in the debugger i see:
|pSecurity = NULL
|StackSize = 0
|ThreadFunction = 214D84CD
|pThreadParm = NULL
|CreationFlags = 0
\pThreadId = 214D84DD

Answer (score 1):

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
  __in_opt   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  __in       SIZE_T dwStackSize,
  __in       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  __in_opt   LPVOID lpParameter,
  __in       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  __out_opt  LPDWORD lpThreadId
);
```

you are passing them wrong. Since in stdcall, you have to push the  argument in a reverse order, lpThreadId should be pushed first. Thus 214D84CD and 214D84DD should be flipped.

Comment: i'm so sorry... i'm wrong to cut and paste the code in my post, my order is like you said and i confirm that not works... thank you...

Comment: What's return value when you call the function? if it's null, what's the value of LastErr (in Registers screen)

Comment: EAX=00000184
LastErr=ERROR_SUCCESS (00000000)
214D84DD=00000840 (it changes)

Comment: and you're saying that the breakpoint at 214D84CD is not being triggered?

Comment: it is triggered only if i execute after CreateThread other threads of my application, but not in my "waiting loop" (see the post). many thanks.

Comment: call Sleep(0) after calling CreateThread, or (even better) replace the "waiting loop" with sleep

Comment: To add to @JosephH comment - does the thread calling CreateThread() have a higher priority than the created thread?  How many cores do you have?  Even if both threads have the same priority, you may have to wait some time, (maybe 200ms), for the new thread to be dispatched, depending on whatever else is running and how the kernel scheduler is feeling today.  If the created thread can only run by the OS applying its anti-starvation algorithm, you can wait up to 30 secs before the new thread gets a cycle or two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually switch to the newly created thread via the 'threads' window.

Comment: I see my new thread in the threads window, but if I double click on it, the debugger show me the ntdll module and not my module. What can I do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is because the CreateThread is in the initialization routine of a DLL.... :(

"During process startup and DLL initialization routines, new threads can be created, but they do not begin execution until DLL initialization is done for the process."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: please be detailed as possible when asking question.